# Password column set in CGridListCtrlEx grid controller

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm using [CGridListCtrlEx](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29064/CGridListCtrlEx-Grid-Control-Based-on-CListCtrl) controller for MFC application. I need to setup a editable password column in side the grid. I already manage to create a editable column in the grid but need some help to make it like password field (otherwise cell is just like a text field, showing text by typical characters not by '*'). here goes my current code.

```
CGridListCtrlEx dirListView;
CGridColumnTrait* pTrait = new CGridColumnTraitEdit;    
dirListView.InsertColumnTrait(1, _T("Password"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 150, 0, pTrait);
dirListView.SetItem(0, 1, LVIF_TEXT, _T("something"), -1, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you ask the author directly on the codeproject?

Looking at the code I find that it is very easy. Straight after you create `pTrait` use `SetStyle()` method to set ES_PASSWORD style, like this:

```
((CGridColumnTraitEdit*)pTrait)->SetStyle(((CGridColumnTraitEdit*)pTrait)->GetStyle() | ES_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: I think it is better to ask the author directly on the codeproject. Just use the Comments and Discussions section on the bottom of the article there